# atoi in c frustration

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, atoi

I am lost here. What is the purpose? To take a string and make it an int? Or to convert a character into ASCII? If I use any number for char s[] I get that number returned. If I use any letter I get a 0. Is this output correct? How can I test for return type to know that the conversion took place?

```
//atoi: convert s to integer

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int atoi(char s[])
{
    int i, n;

    n = 0;
    for (i = 0; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'; ++i)
        n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
    return n;
}
int main()
{
    char s[] = "7";
    printf("atoi = %d\n", atoi(s)); //atoi = 7...is this correct?
    return 0;
}
```

and in K&Rs second version I get an error that the left operand of the if statement must be I-value. I copied this word for word from the book. What did I do wrong?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//atoi: convert s to integer; version 2

int atoi(char s[])
{
    int i, n, sign;

    for (i = 0; isspace(s[i]); i++) //skip white space
        ;
    sign = (s[i] == '-') ? -1 : 1;
    if (s[i] == '+' || s[i] = '-') //skip sign
        i++;
    for (n = 0; isdigit(s[i]); i++)
        n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
    return sign * n;
}
int main()
{
    char s[] = "9";
    printf("atoi = %d\m", atoi(s));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `atoi()` is for 'ASCII to integer' conversion; it takes a string containing an integer and returns the result, or 0 if there's nothing convertible.

Comment: "If I use any number for char s[] I get that number returned. If I use any letter I get a 0. Is this output correct?" - yes

Comment: `if (s[i] == '+' || s[i] = '-')` is doing an assignment in the 2nd half.   This means your compiler warnings are not fully enabled or you have a weak compiler.  Suggest enabling all warnings or changing compilers.

Comment: unless you're writing a stdlib for C, don't name the function like the ones in the standard

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you did not "copy this word for word from the book".

You are using *assignment* instead of *comparison* inside the `if` statement.

**Change this:**

```
s[i] = '-'
```

**To this:**

```
s[i] == '-'
```

Answer (score 1):

My `atoi` man page reads (in part),

> The `atoi()` function converts the initial portion of the string  pointed
>   to by `nptr` to `int`.  The behavior is the same as
>
> ```
> strtol(nptr, NULL, 10);
> ```
>
> except that `atoi()` does not detect errors.

**tl;dr**

Yes. `atoi("7")` should be `7`. And the standard `atoi` can be found in `stdlib.h`

Comment: The `atoi` function has be (re)written by the poster

Comment: @EdHeal It's still taking "7" and returning `7`.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `atoi()` looks correct, though a leading plus sign or minus sign probably ought to be processed to be compatible with C library implementations.

The main program could use work, but as far as coding methodology goes, you might add several test cases to prove that typical types of input work correctly:

```
int main()
{
    const char tests[] = {"7", "0", "10", "99", "1000", "9999", "11111",
                         "99999", "12345678"};
    int j;
    for (j = 0;  test[j];  ++j)
         printf("atoi(%s) = %d\n", tests[j], atoi(tests[j]));
    return 0;
}
```